# How to use a changing variable value in a while loop | Python

Tags: python

I have a python program and a server that written with flask.
The thing I want to do is send a request to the server about is there any new order.
Server returns a JSON file as response if there is an `active: True` value in JSON should run my script. While script is running my program should continue to send request because while program running `active` value can be change to `False`. If  `active: False` script should stop but I have to continue to send request to the server for checking the new orders.

I am adding an example below. If you have any question marks in your mind please let me know:

```
import time

def read_active_data():
    pass

def my_func(active):
    while True:
        print("my_func is active")
        if active == False:
            break


count=0
active=False

while True:
    if count%10==0:
        active= read_active_data()
    if active==True:
        my_func(active)
    time.sleep(1)
    count+=1
```

Comment: Don't write `if x == True` and `if x == False`.  Just write `if x` and `if not x`.  Explicitly comparing a known `bool` to `True` or `False` is pointless and bad style.

Comment: What is question in here ?

Comment: In this code, `my_func()` is always called with `active = True`, and therefore the condition `if active == False` will never be true, so the loop will run forever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

count=0
active= False

def set_active():
    global active
    global count
    while True:
        if count%10==0:
            if active:
                active=False
                print("Inactive")
            else:
                active=True
                print("Active")
        time.sleep(1)

def kronos():
    global count
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        count+=1
        print("Count is: ",count)

def execute():
    global active
    while True:
        if active:
            print("Executing")
        else :
            print("Not executing")
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Thread(target=set_active)
    t2 = Thread(target=kronos)
    t3 = Thread(target=execute)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
```